# React - data "outside" component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I just using some tailwind components and i what is a please difference between have "data" inside component or outside component? What is difference in backgroud and better practice?

```
const people = [
  {
    name: 'Jane Cooper',
    title: 'Regional Paradigm Technician',
    },

  {
    name: 'Karl von etwas',
    title: 'Regional Paradigm Technician',
    },  
] 

export default function Example() {
  return ( ....)
}
```

or

```
export default function Example() {

const people = [
  {
    name: 'Jane Cooper',
    title: 'Regional Paradigm Technician',
    },

  {
    name: 'Karl von etwas',
    title: 'Regional Paradigm Technician',
    },  
] 
  return ( ....)
}
```

Comment: In both the cases when the component re-renders you won't see any changes because you are not using state, you are using variable

Comment: Thanks Sachiv, i using Tailwind Healdess UI. This will fix the state problem. But i just dont know if is some difference if i using data in compotent or outside

Comment: If the data is static, and doesn't depend on a component's state, it's perfectly fine declaring it outside the component. This has the advantage of avoiding recreating it every time the component re-renders.